# Error Publish to Netlify Nuxt3 + Supabase

Tags: deployment, environment-variables, netlify, supabase, nuxt3

Im trying to deploy my Nuxt3 project with Supabase to Netlify but I am having some trouble.

I am in the deployment settings passing the SUPABASE_URL = xxxx and SUPABASE_KEY = xxxx with the same name and value as I have in my .env file in my Nuxt3 project.

However, after deployment when I enter my site I get Nuxt error screen, saying "Error 500, SupabaseUrl is required"

I am passing the Supabase key/url exactly like I named them in my project, anybody knows what might be wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, quite simple misstake, was trying to publish my /public catalog but it was supose to be /dist.